# Why DoesNotExist while query is exist?

Tags: python, django

I dont know what is wrong with this code. But I actually want to get my query so I use `User.objects.get(pk=mail)` while the `mail` is an string that I got from `request.POST.get('email')` . I try to access my data through the Django Shell, it working fine. but I dont know.
here is the code

---

in **`models.py`**:

```
class User(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=150, primary_key=True)
    pw = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

---

in **`views.py`**:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    mail = request.POST.get('email')
    pwd = request.POST.get('pw')
    a = User.objects.get(pk=mail)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the `url.py` file? Please also post the url you fetch.

Comment: have you tried User.objects.get(email=request.POST.get("email")) ?

Comment: nothing changed, @GiorgiJambazishvili ,

Comment: I dont think urls.py would do anything with this. but since you asked this is it @WillemVanOnsem `urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', dex, name='dex'),
    url(r'^home/$', home, name='home'),
    url(r'^login', login, name='login')
]`

Comment: What if you use `User.objects.get(pk=int(mail))` instead?

Comment: You should check if the email is even being passed correctly into the request - you can do so by adding a `print mail` statement to check if it is not None.

Comment: the error changed to this `TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'`

Comment: and it didnt pass the email, what now? @harsha

Comment: So the problem is with your template/javascript code. Suggest you to remove this question, and ask a fresh question with details related to that.